# Is there a tool that measures Proportional Set Size (PSS) on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

I'm looking for something like [smem](http://www.selenic.com/smem/), but for Windows 7 instead of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the strict answer to your question is negative.

The nearest one can get today (as far as I know) is to use the [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and customize the displayed columns per process to include :

`WS Private` - Amount of working-set memory that is private to the process
`WS Shared` - Amount of process working-set memory that is shared

However, don't give up hope. Process Explorer is under constant development by the ultra-fruitful guru, Mark Russinovich. You could bring up the idea of PSS in the Sysinternals Community [Process Explorer forum](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum2.html) as a feature request. If you explain well your needs, you might have a chance of getting it implemented.

Comment: Thanks, harrymc! Unfortunately, the processes I'm trying to measure use a lot of shared memory, and using Process Explorer as it currently works to add them all up would count that memory multiple times. I posted a feature request here: http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic27956_post135017.html#135017

Answer (score 1):

I think sysinternals now has something like this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Check out smem:
http://www.selenic.com/smem/

Usage examples:

```
Show basic process information      smem
Show library-oriented view          smem -m
Show user-oriented view             smem -u
Show system view                    smem -R 4G -K /path/to/vmlinux -w
Show totals and percentages         smem -t -p
Show different columns              smem -c "name user pss"
Sort by reverse RSS                 smem -s rss -r
Show processes filtered by mapping  smem -M libxml
Show mappings filtered by process   smem -m -P [e]volution
Read data from capture tarball      smem --source capture.tar.gz
Show a bar chart labeled by pid     smem --bar pid -c "pss uss"
Show a pie chart of RSS labeled by name     smem --pie name -s rss
```

Comment: smem is mentioned in the question. The question asks for a similar tool for Windows (smem runs on Linux)